# Attaching molecules on the surface of a particle. A tough one

Tags: modeling

I think this might be a difficult one. So, I have a sphere like this (remove the porosity if it helps in the future explanation)

[image]

I wonder if there is any way I could attach/link hundreds of molecules like this (image below)...

[image]

...on the surface of the sphere. I don't really care about the orientation of the molecules when attached to the surface, just wanting to link several of them (small size) all over the surface

Is it even possible?

thanks

**EDIT**: I ended doing something like this following @Chris' advice. Not sure what I am doing wrong. My single molecule should be converted to something else?. I made a second (and probably stupid) try using the "light", and it worked. Every single light was placed in the sphere

[image]

Comment: You can use a particle system (hairs)

Comment: Geometry nodes also come to mind

Comment: I did it (question edited), but when conducting the geometry nodes with the molecule, something like that happened. Any idea?. An incredibly large molecule swallows the sphere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a sphere, add a monkey/molecule. Add geometry nodes modifier to sphere. Scale the molecule in edit mode as you need it.

With this basic setup you get this:

[image]

if you want random distribution, insert a point distribute node:

[image]

If you want a minimum distance between instances, change to poisson disk:

[image]

**EDIT**: I ended up doing something like this, following @Chris' advice, not sure what I am doing wrong. My single molecule should be converted, formated or something else?. I made a second (and probably stupid) attempt using the "light", and it worked. Every single light was placed in the sphere

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Chris!. You are always ready to answer!, ;)

Comment: you are welcome ;)

Comment: @Edu39 might want to use a proxy sphere with no holes in your case because your molecules might be instanced inside the holes which could look weird

Comment: Thank you @Gorgious, however this concept will be happening in the reality of my material.